# Making Reftex insert `~\cite` instead of `\cite`

Tags: emacs, reftex

I'm a bit new to RefTeX. How can I change the RefTeX configuration so that instead of `\cite{ref}` it automatically inserts `~\cite{ref}` whenever I press <kbd>C-[</kbd> (that `~` adds a space before the citation).
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the variable `reftex-cite-format` via customize or in your init file.  In your init file, this should do the trick:

```lisp
(setq reftex-cite-format
      '((?\C-m . "~\\cite{%l}")
        (?t    . "\\cite{%l}")))
```

After pressing <kbd>C-[</kbd>, you can enter <kbd>RET</kbd> for `~\cite` or <kbd>t</kbd> for a version without `~`.