# automatic tilde(~) before \cite in reftex

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

The question is the same as in [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345452/making-reftex-insert-cite-instead-of-cite), that I want `C-c [` to insert `~\cite` instead of just `\cite`. However, the solution given therein as follows

```lisp
(setq reftex-cite-format
  '((?\C-m . "~\\cite{%l}")
    (?t    . "\\cite{%l}")))
```

somehow does not work for me.

I tried the suggestion in the mail list [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2010-03/msg00037.html),

```lisp
(setq reftex-format-cite-function 
  '(lambda (key fmt)
     (let ((cite (replace-regexp-in-string "%l" key fmt)))
       (if (or (= ?~ (string-to-char fmt))
               (member (preceding-char) '(?\ ?\t ?\n ?~)))
           cite
         (concat "~" cite)))))
```

which does work for me, except the following complication, that when I already have something like `~\cite[xxx]`, and I would like to insert another citation, say, `yyy`. Given the cursor is placed as in `~\cite[xxx(cursor here)]`, if insert `yyy` using `C-c [`, I would then get `~\cite[xxx,~yyy]`, which certainly does not compile correctly.

Anything I can to to achieve insertion of ~ on first call of `C-c [` and omit ~ on second and further call? Many thanks!

---

### Update

Congratulations on my `Tumbleweed` badge earned from this post! (╯‵□′)╯︵┻━┻

I tried the following tweak of the [mail list answer](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2010-03/msg00037.html),

```lisp
(setq reftex-format-cite-function 
  '(lambda (key fmt)
     (let ((cite (replace-regexp-in-string "%l" key fmt)))
       (if (or (= ?~ (string-to-char fmt))
               (member (preceding-char) '(?\ ?\t ?\n ?~ ?{ ?,))
               (member (following-char) '(?} ))
     )
           cite
         (concat "~" cite)))))
```

and it's working well so far. It seems that considering more preceding characters and also including following character helps.